# Clisp Error: PRINC: argument is not a stream

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I'm trying to write to a file in Common Lisp, but I keep getting a "file is not a stream" error:

```
[1]> (open "file.txt" :direction :output :if-does-not-exist :create :if-exists :supersede)
#<output buffered file-stream character #P"file.txt">
[2]> (princ 'Hello "file.txt")

*** - princ: argument "file.txt" is not a stream
```

Even attempting to close the file returns an error:

```
[4]> (close "file.txt")

*** - no-applicable-method: When calling #<standard-generic-function close>
with arguments ("file.txt"), no method is applicable.
```

The file was properly created, so I thought it might be a permissions issue, but that doesn't seem to be it.
I've Googled this error without any luck so far. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

PS: I'm running Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa with CLISP 2.49 (2010-07-07)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use open files, you must save the return value of `open` and uses it as the second argument to `princ`. You must also use that same return value as an argument to `close`.

This is usually done with the convenience macro [with-open-file](http://l1sp.org/cl/with-open-file).

The [files chapter of Practical Common Lisp](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/files-and-file-io.html) shows how to use these and other functions and macros.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did read about `with-open-file`, but I don't believe I'm allowed to use that for my assignment.
So instead I did:
`(setq file (open "file.txt" :direction :output :if-does-not-exist :create :if-exists :supersede))
(princ 'Hello file)
(close file)`
Which worked just fine.

Comment: @LePoufCelebre Note that this isn't really any different from any other programming language.  In C, for instance, you'd do `int fd = open("foo.txt",...);  write(fd, ...);` not `open("foo.txt",...); write("foo.txt",...);`.  Or in java, you'd do `FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("foo.txt"); out.write(...)`, not `FileOutputStream out = new FIleOutputStream("foo.txt"); "foo.txt".write(...);`.

Comment: Thank you @JoshuaTaylor, I did not know this.